# Simplifying code blocks with functions [Python]

Tags: python, function, simplify

Im searching for a way to simplify my code via functions. 90% of my operation are equal and only differ from the if condition.

E.g.

```
if isFile:
    
    fFound = False
    for key in files:
        if item["path"] in key:
            fFound = True
            for c in cmds.keys():
                if item["path"] in cmds[c]["files"]:
                    ifxchecker(item["requiredIFX"], cmds[c]["ifx_match"])

            outputCFG()

    if not fFound:
        notFound.append(item['path'])


else:
    dir = item["path"][:-1]
    pFound = False
    for key in files:
        if dir in key:
            pFound = True
            for c in cmds.keys():
                for file in cmds[c]["files"]:
                    if dir in file:
                        ifxchecker(item["requiredIFX"], cmds[c]["ifx_match"])

            outputCFG()

    if not pFound:
        notFound.append(dir)
```

My code is working fine, I'm just trying to get the most of it in a function and only differ from these small if conditions. I can't find a way to simplify it and I'm not even sure if there is.

I did some small functions as you see but I think there would be a better way to simplify the whole construct.

Comment: Put the code `if x in key` in a method ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately can't test it, because multiple vars and methods are not defined, but it seems to work. Maybe using `is_dir` bool variable instead of elem will be better, if you'd like: replace `elem` with `is_dir` and add the following line to the beginning of function:

```
elem = item["path"][:-1] if is_dir else item["path"]
```

```
def do_stuff(elem, files, item, cmds, notFound):
    fFound = False
    for key in files:
        if elem in key:
            fFound = True
            for c in cmds.keys():
                if elem in cmds[c]["files"]:
                    ifxchecker(item["requiredIFX"], cmds[c]["ifx_match"])

            outputCFG()

    if not fFound:
        return elem


if isFile:
    res = do_stuff(item["path"], files, item, cmds)
    if res is not None:
        notFound.append(res)
else:
    do_stuff(item["path"][:-1], files, item, cmds)
    if res is not None:
        notFound.append(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like that with @azro method:

```
def cfgFunction(x):
    global file
    fFound = False
    for file in files:
        if x in file:
            fFound = True
            for group in cmds.keys():
                if x in cmds[group]["files"]:
                    ifxchecker(item["requiredIFX"], cmds[group]["ifx_match"])

            outputCFG()
if not fFound:
    notFound.append(x)
```